# From Year over Year to Quarter on Quarter growth rate in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, data.table

I have inflation data that consists of YoY growth rates (for example: 2022Q1 growth compared to 2021Q1). I would like to calculate QoQ (for example: 2022Q2 growth compared to 2022Q1) growth rates from this data. Anyone familiar with the issue?

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Country = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA"), Year = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2024, 2024, 2024, 
2024, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025), Date = c(2020.25, 2020.5, 2020.75, 
2021, 2021.25, 2021.5, 2021.75, 2022, 2022.25, 2022.5, 2022.75, 
2023, 2023.25, 2023.5, 2023.75, 2024, 2024.25, 2024.5, 2024.75, 
2025, 2025.25, 2025.5, 2025.75, 2026), Indicator = c("Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation", 
"Inflation", "Inflation", "Inflation"), value = c(2.1024427605483, 
0.444735189312673, 1.25384590366553, 1.20009413517206, 1.89726417599199, 
4.81322838330593, 5.29054506348963, 6.72125135918682, 8.00038959034828, 
8.58063131836198, 8.31761217342506, 7.06163784057556, 5.81123356449678, 
3.7796205530483, 2.91085957621091, 2.71663590514395, 2.32216909577692, 
2.30600928886402, 2.29827514628642, 2.27283842072121, 2.14624891760036, 
2.1114094124697, 2.09257240400826, 2.087356375294), Unit = c("% growth over same period of previous year", 
"% growth over same period of previous year", "% growth over same period of previous year", 
"% growth over same period of previous year", "% growth over same period of previous year", 
"% growth over same period of previous year", "% growth over same period of previous year", 
"% growth over same period of previous year", "% growth over same period of previous year", 
"% growth over same period of previous year", "% growth over same period of previous year", 
"% growth over same period of previous year", "% growth over same period of previous year", 
"% growth over same period of previous year", "% growth over same period of previous year", 
"% growth over same period of previous year", "% growth over same period of previous year", 
"% growth over same period of previous year", "% growth over same period of previous year", 
"% growth over same period of previous year", "% growth over same period of previous year", 
"% growth over same period of previous year", "% growth over same period of previous year", 
"% growth over same period of previous year")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you describe how QoQ is calculated and provide any code you've written so far? You can calculate the raw change from each quarter using `df %>% arrange(Date) %>% mutate(QoQ = value - lag(value, 1))`.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have any calculated for these YoY changes, it's the inflation data. I need to convert these YoY growths to QoQ growths. It would be easier if the CPI index, from which these Yoy growths are calculated, would be present in the data set, but now i have only these YoY growths and that is the problem.

Comment: You're using economic terms that people on StackOverflow likely won't recognize (e.g. QoQ, YoY, CPI). You should edit your question to describe (in words or using mathematical equations) how these things are calculated using the information present in `df`; only after can `dplyr` syntax be written.

Comment: This is an algebra problem not an R problem.  But, in any case your data set won't work because you are trying to solve two equations with two unknowns.  Why not just get the periodic data from FRED or something.

Comment: As pointed out you can't mathematically derive the QoQ numbers from the YoY numbers but you can calculate the following.  If the YoY percentage is x then convert it to a ratio r = x/100+1.  Then r/r', where r' is the prior quarter's ratio, is the QoQ ratio divided by the year-ago QoQ ratio.